# Find distribution with given mean and variance

Tags: distributions

I have an exercise with which I'm currently struggling:

> Consider a random sample $\big\{X_n\big\}_{n=1}^N$ from a normal distribution having mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. What is the distribution of $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N (X_n - \overline{X}_N)^2}{\sigma^2}$?

Could anyone give me some hints in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of the sample variance?

Comment: Not quite. However, as far as i've seen during my reading on wikipedia, the variance of $\overline{X}_N$ should be $\frac{s}{\sqrt{N}}$ with $s$ the sample standard deviation...

Comment: Are you studying from a text book or from lecture notes? If so, there's probably something there about the distribution of (a multiple of) $S^2$.

Comment: Hmm, just required work ahead of class.So there are basically no lecture notes nor a book...

Comment: "Required work" sounds like you should have enough information to answer the question. Otherwise, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance

Comment: the numerator is a scalar and the denominator is a scalar.  So what is the distribution of a scalar?

Comment: @grldsndrs: normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mark999 has cracked it.  The numerator is the standard error.  If you have a look at the wiki [chi squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance)you will see that formula for the chi squared distribution, which is the same as the formula you have given, if you substitute the formula for the standard error in for the numerator.  I think your answer is chi square distribution